# Want to disable submit button if current user has submitted before

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to make it so that my submit button disables if you've already submitted the form.

I store your current_user.id when you submit. If you try again you should be met with a submit button that is disabled.

I've been trying to write this with if else statements but it just gets clumsy and doesn't work.

This is what I've tried:

```
<% if @f.current_user.id.present? %>
 <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% else %>
 <p>Disable code here</p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: Taking into account the additional info given in the comments the answer is totally rewritten.

First, in the controller you need to check if `current_user` has posted before:

```
# In controller action
@user_already_submitted = Answer.where(user_id: current_user.id,
    application_id: @answer.application_id).count > 0
```

And then in the view:

```
<%= form_for @answer do |f| %>
  <!-- rest of the form -->
  <%= f.submit "Submit", :disabled => @user_already_submitted %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @Laas got this error: undefined method `current_user' for nil:NilClass this is my database setup on f (@answer) s17.postimg.org/rjecvmumn/… I suspect it isn't checking if the current_user it matches the column user_id and that's the error? The form_for is like this: <%= form_for @answer do |f| %>

Comment: OK, I assumed that you asked only about the disabling part and had rest of it figured out already. Adjusted my answer.

Comment: @Laas that doesn't work either. It still allows the form to be submitted. Which is weird. On another side however my server side is denying it, so that's working.

Comment: Do the `@answer.user_id` and `current_user.id` actually match? Verify that e.g. using `Rails.logger`.

Comment: Another question is: which do you actually want - show a disabled button, or show some text instead. I will put an example with the latter too.

Comment: @Laas yes they do. This is how I block them server side:
  validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :application_id 
  }

So I check that each application_id only have 1 unique user id

Comment: OK, your question seems to be misleading. If I understand now correctly, the `@answer` is a **new** answer, therefore does not have `user_id` set, but the `current_user` has previously submitted, therefore the validation catches the new submit.

Comment: @Laas the answer is Answer.new yes. I'm sorry about being misleading it's hard to describe the problem you're trying to figure out when you don't know how to, then try to title it. What I want is that if you have already submitted a 'new' than it should disable.